# check that a collection is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you check that `data.results` in the following is not empty before trying to perform actions on it?

```
$.getJSON(myurl, function(data) {
  // if data.results is not empty 
  // {
  //    console.log(data.results.size);
  // }

});
```

Comment: depends on the shape of data. post an exemplar.

Comment: I just added a data sample to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (data != null && data.results != null && data.results.length > 0) {
    // the array is not empty
}
```

Comment: The above code has superfluous parts. `if (data)` is the same as if `(data != null)` You can just write `if (data && data.results && data.results.length > 0)`

Comment: @Šime, that's correct but I prefer to be more explicit. It's just a matter of personal coding style.

Comment: I must correct myself. `if (data)` and `if (data != null)` is not the same.

Comment: for some reason `data.results` is giving me undefined, so I had to do just: `if (data != null && data.length > 0)` and that is working for me

Answer (score 2):

I usually use something like this:

```
if (data != null && data.results != null && data.results.size != 0) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

how about doing this one?

```
if(data!=undefined){
// do logic here
}
```